# How can I fetch git objects using the smart protocol (raw) over http?

Tags: git

I'm trying to fetch the annotation of tag "v2.4.2" from github.com/git/git using the git smart protocol over http.

// Get the refs

```
curl -H "User-Agent: git/1.8.1" -v  https://github.com/git/git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

Returns the refs:

```
.....
003e2be062dfcfd1fd4aca132ec02a40b56f63776202 refs/tags/v2.4.1
0041aaa7e0d7f8f003c0c8ab34f959083f6d191d44ca refs/tags/v2.4.1^{}
003e29932f3915935d773dc8d52c292cadd81c81071d refs/tags/v2.4.2
00419eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 refs/tags/v2.4.2^{}
```

// Make the upload pack request

```
printf "0031want 00419eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785\n0024have 003e2be062dfcfd1fd4aca132ec02a40b56f63776202\n0000" | curl -H "User-Agent: git/1.8.1" -v  -d @- https://github.com/git/git/git-upload-pack -H "Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```

This returns nothing. I'm wondering what's wrong in the request (i.e did I  miscalculate the hex?)

```
Warning: --trace-ascii overrides an earlier trace/verbose option
== Info: Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
== Info:   Trying 192.30.252.130...
== Info: Connected to github.com (192.30.252.130) port 443 (#0)
== Info: TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
== Info: Server certificate: github.com
== Info: Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
== Info: Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
=> Send header, 170 bytes (0xaa)
0000: POST /git/git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
0028: Host: github.com
003a: Accept: */*
0047: User-Agent: git/1.8.1
005e: Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
0093: Content-Length: 110
00a8: 
=> Send data, 110 bytes (0x6e)
0000: 0031want 00419eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d7850024have 00
0040: 3e2be062dfcfd1fd4aca132ec02a40b56f637762020000
== Info: upload completely sent off: 110 out of 110 bytes
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
== Info: Server GitHub Babel 2.0 is not blacklisted
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
<= Recv header, 52 bytes (0x34)
0000: Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
<= Recv header, 18 bytes (0x12)
0000: Pragma: no-cache
<= Recv header, 53 bytes (0x35)
0000: Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: Vary: Accept-Encoding
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: 0
0003: 
== Info: Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
```

Why am I trying this?

- I don't have write access to the file system
- Avoid fetching unnecessary data (i.e the commits)
- Standard API/Protocol

Answer (score 13):

### Commit hex

You didn't *miscalculate* the hex, but you're not passing the correct value.  Remember that each line in the [smart protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Smart-Protocol) is preceded by a length count:

```
<length><data>
```

So for a line that looks like this:

```
00419eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 refs/tags/v2.4.2^{}
```

You need to discard the first four characters, which makes the actual commit hex:

```
9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785
```

### Request format

When `POST`ing a request, the `have` and `want` lines are supposed to be separated by a newline, but if you take a look at the output from `curl`, you can see that there is no newline:

```
=> Send data, 110 bytes (0x6e)
0000: 0031want 00419eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d7850024have 00
0040: 3e2be062dfcfd1fd4aca132ec02a40b56f637762020000
```

You need to use `--data-binary` instead of `--data`:

```
--data-binary @-
```

You need to prefix these lines with a length count, and you need to end with a line consisting of `0000`:

```
0032want 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785
0032have 2be062dfcfd1fd4aca132ec02a40b56f63776202
0000
```

### Debugging tips

You can set `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1` in your environment if you want to get copious debugging information from `git` to see exactly what it's sending back and forth.

### And that's all he wrote

I'm not able to get a response myself, even given the above information, but I figured it would help.

### Update

So, this was fun.

I set up a git server locally (using `git http-backend` and [thttpd](http://acme.com/software/thttpd/)), and ran `tcpdump` to grab the traffic generated by a `git remote update` operation.  It turns out that the you need to separate the `want` and `have` directives with a null command, which is `0000` (no newline, because the length encodes newlines, too).  That is:

```
<length>want <commitid><newline>
0000<length>have <commitid><newline>
<length>done
```

E.g:

```
0032want 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785
00000032have 2be062dfcfd1fd4aca132ec02a40b56f63776202
0009done
```

That gives me:

```
0000: POST /git/git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
0028: Host: github.com
003a: Accept: */*
0047: Content-type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
007c: User-agent: git/1.8
0091: Content-Length: 113
00a6: 
=> Send data, 113 bytes (0x71)
0000: 0032want 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785.00000032have 2
0040: be062dfcfd1fd4aca132ec02a40b56f63776202.0009done.
== Info: upload completely sent off: 113 out of 113 bytes
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
<= Recv header, 52 bytes (0x34)
0000: Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
<= Recv header, 18 bytes (0x12)
0000: Pragma: no-cache
<= Recv header, 53 bytes (0x35)
0000: Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: Vary: Accept-Encoding
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 4 bytes (0x4)
0000: 31
<= Recv data, 51 bytes (0x33)
0000: 0031ACK 2be062dfcfd1fd4aca132ec02a40b56f63776202.
<= Recv data, 6 bytes (0x6)
0000: 1fff
<= Recv data, 1370 bytes (0x55a)
0000: PACK.......[..x...An.0...z.?`..d.*..@..z..(.tu......>~B.....]..8
0040: 2...j).OQ}..#.....'......[..8K..t..,%.S..u..@l..XT...o......'...
[....]
```

### Double-bonus update

You can use the `git unpack-objects` command to extract the packfile.  As you can see from the above trace, you first get back a length-encoded response (
`0031ACK 2be062dfcfd1fd4aca132ec02a40b56f63776202`) followed by the pack data, so you need to discard that first line:

```
$ git init tmprepo
$ cd temprepo
$ tail -n +2 output_from_curl | git unpack-objects
Unpacking objects: 100% (91/91), done.
$ find .git/objects -type f | head -3
$ git cat-file -p dc940e63c453199dd9a7285533fbf2355bab03d1
/*
 * GIT - The information manager from hell
 *
 * Copyright (C) Linus Torvalds, 2005
 *
 * This handles basic git sha1 object files - packing, unpacking,
 * creation etc.
 */
[...]
```

Comment: I think the double bonus does't apply due the lack of access to the filesystem.

Comment: Not even to a temporary location?  You're going to need to unpack the pack files and *then* extract content from the object files, which is either going to require writing your own git processing code or some sort of filesystem location.

Comment: Yeah, not even temporary. The apllication is basically sandboxed.  I Hoped there would be a way to process the data on the fly without to actually save it.